# Unresolved externals during python pymqi installation

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm installing the pymqi package on Win7

`pip install pymqi-1.7.2.tar.gz`

but all I get is an error

`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit_pymqe`

Here is full listing from the cmd:

```
pip install pymqi-1.7.2.tar.gz
Processing c:\pymqi-1.7.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pymqi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pymqi ... error
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, toke
nize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ELYASH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-dktwad4n-build\\setup.py';f=getattr
(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ELYASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4f_xo1yupip-wheel-
--python-tag cp36:
  Building PyMQI client 64bits
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  copying pymqi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  copying pymqi\CMQC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  copying pymqi\CMQCFC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  copying pymqi\CMQXC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  copying pymqi\CMQZC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi
  running build_ext
  building 'pymqi.pymqe' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pymqi
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3
/GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYQMI_SERVERBUILD=0 "-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include
" -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1
\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include" "-IC:\Prog
ram Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\cplus\include" /Tcpymqi/pymqe.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Rele
ase\pymqi/pymqe.obj
  pymqe.c
  pymqi/pymqe.c(249): warning C4013: 'PyString_AsString' undefined; assuming extern returning int

  pymqi/pymqe.c(249): warning C4047: '=': 'MQPTR' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(250): warning C4013: 'PyString_Size' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(251): warning C4047: '=': 'MQPTR' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(726): warning C4013: 'PyString_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(730): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection
from 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(730): warning C4024: 'strncpy': different types for formal and actual parameter 2

  pymqi/pymqe.c(1081): warning C4047: '=': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1089): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'PMQCHAR' of greater
size
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1159): warning C4013: 'PyInt_Check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1168): warning C4013: 'PyInt_AsLong' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1182): warning C4047: '=': 'MQCHAR *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

  pymqi/pymqe.c(1190): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'MQBYTE *' of greater
 size
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1391): warning C4013: 'PyString_FromString' undefined; assuming extern returning
int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1391): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'in
t'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1454): warning C4013: 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' undefined; assuming extern ret
urning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1454): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'in
t'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1542): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule4' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1544): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'in
t'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1551): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1551): warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString': different types for formal and actu
al parameter 3
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1552): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1552): warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString': different types for formal and actu
al parameter 3
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1561): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1561): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1564): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1564): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1567): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1567): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1570): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1570): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1573): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1573): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1576): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1576): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1579): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1579): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1582): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1582): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1585): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1585): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1588): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1588): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1591): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1591): warning C4024: 'PyList_Append': different types for formal and actual para
meter 2
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1606): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'int'
  pymqi/pymqe.c(1606): warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString': different types for formal and actu
al parameter 3
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMEN
TAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSp
here MQ\tools\Lib64" /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\PCb
uild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits
\NETFXSDK\4.6\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" "
/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\lib64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere
MQ\tools\lib" mqic.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_pymqe build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pymqi/pymqe.obj /OUT
:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymqi\pymqe.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\
pymqi\pymqe.cp36-win_amd64.lib
  LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit_pymqe
  build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pymqi\pymqe.cp36-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link
.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

What can be a reason for such problem and how could I install the package?

I have also tried installation by setup.py, but since the computer I install the package on does not have Internet connection due to security reasons, installation of all the packages manually will take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. As far as I understand this version of pymqi-1.7.2.tar.rz is not suitable for python 3

Install the version of py3mqi-1.6.0.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you! The package is now successfully installed. However I still have troubles with the other packages i.e. 'exceptions'. Since I don't have internet connection on the computer, the installation is pretty challenging. Using anaconda is also not an option because it requires internet connection as well. I have installed python-docx, libxml and lots of other packages but I still have the same problem with 'exceptions'.